# How to control the volume of audio track in mediastream object?

Tags: javascript, audiotrack, mediastream

I have been working on a audio/video streaming site using the AWS IVS service in angular. I have created a media stream object by creating capture when the audio elements plays the music and then add the media stream object to IVS client. Now, I want to control the volume of the audio track before passing it to the IVS client. Mozilla docs suggests that the volume property is deprecated and no longer should be used. How do I control the volume of my audio track in media stream object and pass it into IVS client?

I tried to use the volume contraint but it is deprecated now according to Mozilla docs site.